# Customize legend entries in pie chart using R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, pie-chart, r-plotly

I am trying to make a pie chart in R using plotly. I have a tibble `(df)` with 4 columns - (1) an observation `(x)`, (2) value of the observation `(y)`, (3) category of the observation `(cat)`, and (4) color of each observation `(colors)`. Colors are unique for each category (every observation within the same category will share the same color). I need each segment of the pie chart to represent each observation with the size of the segment corresponding to the value of the observation. I also need the segments to be colored by their unique category color. I have been able to build such a pie chart.

I am, however, struggling with how to customize the legend. Using `showlegend=TRUE` shows each observation with it's color. I need the legend to showcase each unique category with its distinct color. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Here is some dummy code that models this problem -

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# Initialize variables
df = NULL
x = c("apple", "John", "dog", "lion", "strawberry", "Liz", 
      "cat", "peach", "banana", "elephant", "pear", "tiger")
y = c(1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 1, 6)
cat = c("fruit", "person", "animal", "animal", "fruit", "person", 
        "animal", "fruit", "fruit", "animal", "fruit", "animal")
colors = NULL

# Define colors
for (i in 1:length(cat)) {
    if (cat[i] == "fruit") {
        color = "#FFD700"
    } else if (cat[i] == "animal") {
        color = "#FB8072"
    } else {
        color = "#D3D3D3"
    }
    colors = c(colors, color)
}

# Create data frame
df = as_tibble(cbind(x, y, cat, colors))

# Sort data frame
df = df[order(df$cat, df$x), ]

# Define colors for pie chart
pie_colors = as.character(df$colors)

# Define margins for pie chart
margins = list(l=50, r=50, b=125, t=125)

# Build the pie chart
pie_plt = plot_ly(data=df,
                 values=~y,
                 labels=~x,
                 type="pie",
                 textinfo="label+percent",
                 sort=FALSE,
                 marker=list(colors=pie_colors,
                            line=list(color="black", width=1))) %>%
            layout(autosize=FALSE, margin=margins, showlegend=TRUE)

# Show pie chart:
pie_plt
```